# How to fetch the text of selected ActionLink in MVC3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, html.actionlink

I am having problem with fetching the text of the selected ActionLink

I am displaying the links dynamically after fetching through database like this:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.HobbyName, "Hobbies")</li>
}
```

Now, how shall I fetch the text of selected Link?

I tried this:

```
filename = $('a').text;
alert(filename);
```

But does not to work.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this

```
filename = $('a').text();
```

`text()` is a function, not a property.

**EDIT:**

If you want to get link text when you click in that link try like this

```
$('a').click(function() {
   filename = $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: Make sure that you're using right selector for getting anchor that you want.
This example is working fine, check jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4hDva/

Comment: hi with this i am getting the text of all links in my page how shal i get the text of selected link.Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
filename = $('li a').text();
```

Comment: hi with this i am getting the text of all links in my page how shal i get the text of selected link.Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.ActionLink` renders as standard anchor tags, so you could do something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("ul li").each(function(){
       var text = $(this).find("a").text();
       alert(text);
    });        
});​
```

[**-- SEE DEMO --**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/Aau9M/)

Comment: thanx for this but i din need all of them i jus wanted the current selected link and i have got it now..

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = document,
    arr = []

Array.prototype.forEach.call( d.getElementsByTagName( 'li' ), function ( el ) {
    arr.push( el.firstElementChild.textContent )
} )

alert( arr )
```

Of course this could be optimized if you set some class/id to your elements.